# Downloading file using jQuery ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC grid containing two columns.. DocumentName and a button that when clicked would download the document/open in browser (I am fine with any solution).
Like this
[image]

My controller returns the file like this

```
 public FileResult Render(string file)
 {
   return File(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DocumentFilePath"] + file, GetMime(Path.GetExtension(file)), Path.GetFileName(file));
 }

    [NonAction]
    private string GetMime(string extension)
    {
        string contentType = string.Empty;
        switch (extension.ToLower())
        {
            ...
            case ".png":
                contentType = "image/x-png";
                break;
            ...
        }
   }
```

On client side, when button is clicked, I call a showDocument function

```
 function showDocument(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
    //dataItem.DocumentName holds the name of the document like Build Error_3E53...PNG

    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Render", "Log")',
        data: {file: dataItem.DocumentName},
        success: function (document) {
            window.location = document;
        } 
    });
 }
```

When I click on the button, it gives an error but it appears that its sending the bytes to the console of the browser
[image]

Please let me know what should I do to fix the problem and download/view the file.

Answer (score 0):

Add `dataType` and `responseType` to ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '@Url.Action("Render", "Log")',
  dataType: 'binary',
  xhrFields: {
    responseType: 'blob'
  },
  success: function(blob){
    console.log(blob.size);
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    link.download = "fileName" + ".fileExtension";
    link.click();
  }
});
```

Checkout [file download via ajax](https://codepen.io/chrisdpratt/pen/RKxJNo) example.

Comment: Hi, Thank you. This doesnt work. But do you have a solution which doesn't involve createObjectURL? It seems Google Chrome deprecated it.